# Loading order of PHP functions and classes. Both need to be loaded before the other

Tags: php, database, function, class

I have a little problem with including php functions and classes.
They are sort of depending on each other to be loaded first, so I suppose I'm doing something wrong.

Here's a scenario:

I have an ordinary php function that I would like to do a database request.
But the database class, and stuff, are included after the functions. Meaning that the database instance is not yet loaded when the function is executet. Resulting in this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in
```

If I move the database scripts etc. to before functions are loaded, some functions are not available the for database-script to be added.

Anyone had this issue, and know of a solution to handle this sort of challenge?

**Just FYI:** I have a script that scans the function-folder for `.func-files`, and includes them in a `foreach`-loop.
Same goes for `.class`-files with an autoloader-function.

I could possibly add the functions that requires database to be loaded before after.
But that would require a manual approach to each of these situations.

Comment: Ideally you should be including everything you need, before you actually execute anything. We can't really tell you precisely how to resolve it though, without seeing any code. If you can create a [mre] of the issue we can probably advise you better.

Comment: after further investigation I noticed that the functions that required database access had a parameter that accepted the variable that had the database connection stored. Like function:  
`getSQL($field,$table,$id,$db){ 
    $db->prepare("SELECT $field FROM $table WHERE id = ?); 
}`.  
Would there be a way to not having to pass the $db as a parameter into a function?

Comment: If you want to use it, you'll need to pass that in. There isn't really a good way to avoid that. The question is, why are you trying to do a query before you've included any database-related in the script? Again, it's really hard to suggest the best approach when we don't have any code to provide meaningful context. But this is clearly solveable, because applications in general don't suffer from this kind of circular dependency which you appear to have.